Why when compiling C app with .a and .so libs on Windows' CodeBlocks it ends up with "different os".exe file?
Build provided .exe file which says it is unsupported on current os (Windows), even if target flags were specified.
Can using .a and .so libraries could be a reason for this, and should I recompile library to .lib and .dll and use them instead?

Welcome to Stackoverflow. The difficulty you are trying to describe is quite unclear. You need to show it, not describe it. Improve the question by providing a Minimal Reproducible Example.
